# Where do i find the Source codes from the Pragmatic programmers-iPhone SDK Development book

Tags: iphone

I have just started reading the book and i seem to have a problem with the code from the Tab-Bar project. I dont know where i'll get the source code from for free. can ne1 help me out with that? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: type it out. you'll learn more.

Comment: If you want to learn code you have to write it, not read it, not copy/paste it.

Comment: So far i was doing that! typed each and every example from the book. But this tab-bar example doesn't work! Neway i got the source code its on http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/source_code. Thanks for the help neway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the main web page (http://pragprog.com) and found these link: "Where can I find sample code and errata."  Clicking that I found: "Where do I find the code for my book?"

Alternatively I searched for the book on their site and found this link: "Code".  Clicking that link I found this link: "Download .zip".

It really is that simple to use the Internet. :-)